# Большая сумма вложенного списка

Tags: python, матрицы

Задача с LeetCode.
Дан двоичный массив, необходимао найти в нём подмассив с большей суммой его элементов и вернуть эту самую сумму.

```
def wealth_cust(accounts):
    largest_acc = 0
    for account in accounts:
        current_account = sum(account)
        if current_account > largest_acc:
            largest_acc = current_account

    return largest_acc
```

Вроде всё должно так работать, но LeetCode возвращает ошибку

```
NameError: global name 'Solution' is not defined
    ret = Solution().maximumWealth(param_1)
Line 29 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 39 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Впервые столкнулся с LeetCode, возможно пока что просто не совсем понимаю как с ним работать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LeetСode даёт прототип функции, и нужно использовать именно его, а не свою функцию. Система проверки вызывает `Solution.maximumWealth` с разными аргументами (я взял то, что нашлось на LC c таким именем, не факт, что вы имели в виду именно эту задачу)

```
class Solution:
    def maximumWealth(self, accounts: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        здесь пишете тело метода
```

Comment: Теперь понятно,возможно я случайно удалил прототип функции когда менял язык. Большое спасибо